# Error of initialization of IIS 7

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7

- My Windows Server is in Portuguese Brazil.
- Sorry , I'm not fluent English.

After an upgrade my Windows Server 2008 R2 spent facing problems with IIS (version 7 ) .

Whenever I try to start the IIS introduces me the message " Could not start WAS due to dependency group," something always . I checked all dependent services and nothing.

See the image the IIS my reports.

[image]

> **Name of the service with the error translated image:**
>   1. Activation service windows processes 
>   2. World Wide Web Publishing Service

While attempting to start the service I get errors with:

[image]

> **Image Text translated into English:** 
>   Line 1: Windows Process Activation Service failed to start. 
>   Line 2: Incorrect parameter.

### Observations:

- I can not perform system restore due to the large amount of files and software that will be lost.
- Problem now presented only after the automatic update.
- Already fully uninstalled and reinstalled IIS.
- Already removed, renamed the inetpub folder and also without results.
- Booting dependent services the same error appears.

Comment: Try installing Windows Process Activation Service from roles and features in server manager. if it is already installed then re install it.

Comment: I've done this procedure thousands of times. Have uninstalled and installed IIS again, but always the same error.

Comment: Not IIS, Windows Process Activation Service. if you have done it before, then reinstall framework and then try. I was able to manage this error by doing so.